# getopts not working in bash script

Tags: bash, unix

```
#! bin/bash
# code for train.sh
   while getopts "f:" flag
    do
         case $flag in 
             f)
               echo "Hi" 
               STARTPOINT = $OPTARG
               ;;
         esac
    done

    echo Test range: $4
    echo Train range: $3

    #path of experiment folder and data folder:
    EXP_DIR="$1"
    DATA_DIR="$2"
    echo Experiment: $EXP_DIR
    echo DataSet: $DATA_DIR
    echo file: $STARTPOINT


I ran the command > ./train.sh test1  test2 test3 test4  -f testf
```

and got the output

```
Test range: test4
Train range: test3
Experiment: test1
DataSet: test2
file:
```

So getopts option does not seem to work for some reason as you can see the nothing is printed after file and also echo "Hi" command is not executed in the case statement. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to put any options before naked parameters

```
./train.sh -f testf test1  test2 test3 test4
```

with output

```
Hi
Test range: test4
Train range: test3
Experiment: test1
DataSet: test2
file: testf
```

You need a couple of changes too

```
while getopts "f:" flag
do
     case $flag in
         f)
           echo "Hi" 
           STARTPOINT=$OPTARG
           shift
           ;;
     esac
     shift
done
```

To set the environment variable and shift the got option out of the way

Comment: Is it possible to have getopts after the positional arguments or they have to before the positional arguments? Why are you using two shifts one inside the case statement and one outside?

Comment: One shift is to deal with the -f and the other for testf. So the code would be more general if there were an option without a parameter. You can probably `shift` your naked parameters off then call `getopt` to process any options after

Answer (score 2):

Two points:

1. the options parsing must occur before non-options parsing.
2. the shift to remove the options can occur once, after all options
   have been parse.

Used on a `while`, the `getopts` function does not need a shift within the loop. However, after the `while getopts` completes, a shift *is* needed in order to process the non-option arguments.  The variable `OPTIND` indicates the index of the next non-option to be parsed, and this value can be used in a `shift` command.

Here is an example, where I also include the `h`, `n` and `v` options for "help", "norun" and "verbose" flags:

```
while getopts 'f:hnv' opt ; do
  case "$opt" in 
  h) usage ;; 
  n) norun=1 ;; 
  f) echo "Hi" ; STARTPOINT="$OPTARG" ;; 
  v) verbose=1 ;; 
  esac 
done 
shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))
```

Comment: Thanks Aks for your explanation. It is helpful